# How to trigger a PHP script to send email on specific time stored in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have customer table in MySQL database with `appointment_time` field.
I want to send an email to the customer on time specified in that field.
I have written a PHP script to send an email but don't know how to automatically trigger it on the time specified in database.

Answer (score 4):

google `cron` and read about cron jobs. This is basically how linux/un*x schedule jobs and run them at your specified times and intervals. Even if you are using a shared hosting, they should have a facility to do this for you.

The idea is you tell cron to run your PHP script

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/your/php/script.php

# run this php script every minute
```

and check your database for schedules at this time. Note that most shared hosting WILL NOT allow a cronjob that runs every minute. Most will allow you to run every 5 minutes.